# WS_CLIPCHILDREN does not work when in fullscreen

Tags: c++, winapi, fullscreen

I have a main window created with :

```
if (!fullscreen)
{
    wStyle = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
    wExStyle = WS_EX_TOPMOST;
}
else
{
    wStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
    wExStyle = WS_EX_TOPMOST;
}
```

I have also a child window created runtime with :

```
wStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_CHILD;
wExStyle = WS_EX_TOPMOST;
```

Everything is going well when I am not in fullscreen. (i.e. The child window is well displayed on top of the parent window.)

But, when I am on fullscreen mode, the parent window is painted over the child window which cause an awful flickering.

How to set properties to the main and the child window in order to display well the child window, even in fullscreen mode ?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Is there a way to stop drawing a window ?

Comment: You seem to have several misconceptions about what the different window styles mean.  It can be very confusing.  I suggest reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(v=VS.85).aspx#types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WS_POPUP cannot be used with WS_CHILD. Not positive that's the cause though.

Comment: Is there a way to have a window without title bar, without status bar, without borders... and without using WS_POPUP ?

Comment: @Xavier V.:  Most windows don't have title bars, status bars, borders, etc.  You need to ask for them if you want them.  That's orthogonal to whether you want a child window or a popup window.

Answer (score 2):

Those style flag combinations are invalid.  A child window cannot be a popup nor can it be top-most.  No idea what kind of side effects that might have, never tried to get this wrong intentionally.

Getting stuck on this might be educational but not very practical.  Have you considered using a class library to take care of the gooey stuff?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

What library are you thinking about ?

Comment: There are lots of them: Qt, MFC, wxWidgets, WTL, etcetera.